# SQL:How to find similar strings in a tuple

Tags: sql, pycharm, tuples, difflib

I tried to use difflib to get_close_matches in a tuple data...but it does not work...I have earlier used difflib in a JSON file but couldn't use it in an SQL...[Result expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iJDW.png)I want to find words similar to the input given..even if there is any spelling mistake...for example...if the input is treeeee or TREEEEE or Treeea...my program should consider the nearest match...that is a tree...Similar to the Did you mean? function in GOOGLE. I also tried **SELECT * FROM Dictionary WHERE Expression LIKE '%s** but the problem persists. Please help me solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SQL functions Soundex and DIFFERENCE look like the closest fit.